# Why can't I go to sign in page to Gitlab.com from Browser?

Tags: gitlab, cloudflare

I went to [about.gitlab.com](https://about.gitlab.com). from there I clicked on sign in. The browser keeps showing: "Checking your browser before accessing gitlab.com.". This has been going on for 10 hours. I have Already tried clearing my cookies and restarting my pc. This did not yield any result. My firewall is turned off so it isn't a firewall issue.

Comment: One possible cause: images are blocked in the browser (seems their verification process loads some data with an image content-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems related to a DDOS protection by Cloudflare (since [GitLab has changed ts CDN provider to Cloudflare last March 2020](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/01/16/gitlab-changes-to-cloudflare/)

> GitLab.com users with a whitelist of sites in their firewall setup will need to change what is whitelisted for GitLab.com.
> For the initial change, we will be switching DNS to Cloudflare. This will cause all GitLab.com traffic to be proxied through Cloudflare.
> This change will be visible by changes in DNS records queried for GitLab.com. A [whitelist of IPs can be found here](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/).

The [OP freeroamer90](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13872288/freeroamer90) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086187/why-cant-i-go-to-sign-in-page-to-gitlab-com-from-browser/65086494?noredirect=1#comment115071217_65086494):

- it is working in incognito mode
- the issue seems related to the **Quick Heal Anti Tracker** extension ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-heal-anti-tracker/) or Chrome) which was blocking the site.

Comment: my firewall is turned off. So I shouldn't have to whitelist the IPs. Also, I can access the website on my phone(not on my laptop), so I think the server is not Under DDOS attack. So how can I resolve this? plz help.

Comment: @freeroamer90 Can you check if the error persists with a different browser? (Chrome/FF/IE)

Comment: Yes, it persists in both Edge and Chrome. I also tried it with different networks(My Home broadband and Mobile Hotspot). But on a recommendation, I tried in an Incognito Windows, and it worked. So I have Isolated it to an extension which was on both browsers and seemed to block the site. I have removed it and its now working as expected. Thanks for your time and help @VonC

Comment: @freeroamer90 Great! What was the problematic extension?

Comment: Quickheal Anti Tracker. It came packaged with the antivirus and never even knew it was there :)

Comment: @freeroamer90 Great, thank you for the feedback. I have included your comments in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 17):

This is so extremely frustrating and makes me want to move everything back from GitLab to GitHub.

In my case, the addon that GitLab (actually cloudflare) didn't like was the Chameleon (Random Agent Spoofer) plugin, which I use to prevent tracking/fingerprinting across websites.

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chameleon-ext/

Thanks Cloudflare for depending on fingerprinting and effectively issuing a DOS attack on GitLab customers that use tools to protect themselves.

Answer (score 4):

This also happens when [`privacy.resistFingerprinting`](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-protection-against-fingerprinting) is enabled in Firefox. This is the [relevant GitLab issue (#14234)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/infrastructure/-/issues/14234).

There are also discussions on this on GitLab’s forums:

- [GitLab forum: “Can't Open the signin page. It keeps showing: Checking your browser before accessing gitlab.com”](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/cant-open-the-signin-page-it-keeps-showing-checking-your-browser-before-accessing-gitlab-com/45857)
- [GitLab forum: “Redirect loop on the sign-in page of gitlab.com when using the Tor Browser”](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/redirect-loop-on-the-sign-in-page-of-gitlab-com-when-using-the-tor-browser/50880)

and on the Cloudfare forums:

- [Cloudflare community: “Firefox resistFingerprinting vs. Cloudflare challenge”](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/firefox-resistfingerprinting-vs-cloudflare-challenge/306354)

This is just terrible! As others have mentioned, sites like GitHub have no problem with this. Not a good impression at all from GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any plugins or blockers and this is what worked for me on Windows 11.

1. Turn off Windows Firewall for both public and private networks
2. Open gitlab in Chrome Incognito.