# Running tests with TestCafe and cannot get redirected to GitLab sign-in page. Receive Checking your browser before accessing gitlab.com

Tags: testing, browser, gitlab, automated-tests, testcafe

I am running tests with TestCafe and I cannot get redirected to the GitLab sign-in page. The browser tests are stuck on the "Receive Checking your browser before accessing gitlab.com" page.

[GitLab Checking Browser Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFAMb.png)

I believe the issue is related to [DDOS protection by Cloudflare (since GitLab has changed its CDN provider to Cloudflare in March 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086187/why-cant-i-go-to-sign-in-page-to-gitlab-com-from-browser)

The issue also exists when running tests with Playwright and I have tried multiple browsers Chrome, Firefox, Safari and still experience the same issue.

Does anybody know if there is a way to bypass this limitation with GitLab when running tests in TestCafe?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're right, I also couldn't get to the gitlab.com login form using TestCafe. Unfortunately, there is no workaround here as Cloudflare is specifically designed to prevent access from automation tools, and TestCafe is one of such tools.
If you are testing an application protected with Cloudflare (be it gitlab or something else), I can only recommend you create a separate instance of this application without Cloudflare protection.
If you are trying to use TestCafe as a bot in an application that you don't develop, I'm afraid this is not gonna work.

Comment: Thanks for the response @IlyaAfanasenko. In my case the external Cloud app I am helping to develop gets data from the GitLab Cloud API and we go through the OAuth dance with GitLab but this is where the test fails as it cannot get thru to the login screen. 

Can you help me understand what you mean by **create a separate instance of this application without Cloudflare protection**?  The app is not protected by Cloudfare bit GitLab who we are trying to authenticate against is.

Comment: Speaking of a separate application instance without Cloudflare protection, I was thinking that maybe your application is protected by Cloudflare as well as GitLab, and you are using GitLab as an example because you cannot share a link to your application (since it is not publicly available).

Comment: As for login in GitLab, I still do not see a reliable way to overcome Cloudflare's protection. However, do you really need to log in using a browser? I have not dealt with GitLab, but I believe that, like many other similar services, they provide all the necessary information through the REST API. Specifically, here: [https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/api/openapi/openapi.yaml](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/api/openapi/openapi.yaml) I see a way to authorize with apiKey.

Comment: If, however, you still cannot do without browser authorization, try launching chrome (or firefox) with profiles that are already logged in.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @IlyaAfanasenko.  Will explore if launching the browser with already logged in profiles will help us but we really wanted to test the OAuth dance that the user would encounter using our app.

Comment: Currently, TestCafe is unable to bypass Cloudflare's block. And I don't know a way to test such a scenario in the same way that the user encounters it. If you think you really need it, please create an improvement request in the TestCafe repository ([https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new/choose](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new/choose)). However, do you really want to test someone else's application? After all, GitLab testing is GitLab's responsibility, and I'm sure they test their application very carefully.